# TweetInvi and winRT file or dependencies not found

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, nuget, winjs, tweetinvi

I'm working on creating an Universal Windows Plateform application with WinJS and a Windows RT component. 
I use the TweetInvi in the RT component and call the associate class through JS. I installed TweetInviAPI (v1.1.1) with NuGet package installer so normally the dependencies are installed.

When I try to call TweetInvi I have an exception raised and the following message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tweetinvi, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7247f14397bf67b9' or one of its dependencies. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

Informations WinRT : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tweetinvi, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7247f14397bf67b9' or one of its dependencies. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
```

I already tried to reinstall, refresh packages in my solution. I also tried to fix the `bindingRedirect` but it's quiet complicated and i'm a little bit lost in it. The only other dependencie is `Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` (v5.2.2)

I succeed in making it work on a normal uwp application but not with winjs and windows RT.

If you need any further information feel free to ask.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I use TweetInviAPI 1.2.0 alpha2 + Microsoft.NETCore.UnviersalWindowsPlatform 5.1.0  and i found that my project target .NET core 5.0

I'm digging in log file to find out the dependency that's not working and I found some interesting things for you @Linvi I think: 
Here is the raw part of my logs where the dependencies are not found 
http://pastebin.com/pJHddU3r

and here the a non exhaustive list of the non found dependencies:

- mscorlib
- system.core
- System
- System.net
- System.Net.Http
- System.ComponentModel.Annotations
- System.Net.NetworkInformation
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
- System.ServiceModel.Primitives
- System.ServiceModel.Http
- System.ServiceModel.Duplex
- System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
- System.ServiceModel.Security
  .....

It's the first time i use nugget and it's really a bad experience, I have never seen such a bad package manager. I really want to use TweetInvi because it's the only realistic C# library on the market.

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of the WinRT project you are attempting to create. I will need to see the version of .NET Framework that you are using. Also could you please share the Output of the Nuget installation and share all the dependencies you have on nuget packages.

Thanks

Comment: Here are the information you are asking : [Images](http://imgur.com/a/nhfHi) And the two project are targetting .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Nuget is having a lot of trouble to pick the correct dependency between .NETCore and normal Portable Class Libraries.

For the moment you have 2 solutions :

- Install Tweetinvi 1.2-alpha2 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/1.2.0-alpha2) which I have created just for the purpose of solving this issue.
- Install Tweetinvi version 1.0
- Change the target of the project to become a .NETCore library:

  1. Go to project properties > Library Tab
  2. Click `Target .NET Platform Standard`
  3. Pick .NETStandard 1.6
  4. You can now install Tweetinvi via the Nuget Package Manager.

Obviously this problem will be fixed in the coming release. It is a priority for me to ensure the compatibility with all types of projects.

**Regardless of whether you use it, could you please let me know if the Tweetinvi 1.2-alpha2 works for you.**

Cheers,
Linvi

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Tweetinvi 1.2-alpha2  is not correcting my issue with dependencies. I can't target .NETStandard 1.6 because the windows RT component is a UWP one and UWP is only supporting 1.4 .NETStandard version. I tried some combination with the tweetInvi version with no result.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have created an issue on github : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/382. Could you please post a .zip of a solution that you can use to reproduce your problem.

Thank you.